# Validating CSV file content saved in DB using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I have csv file which will be processed and saved in DB. I need to verify the contents of CSV vs DB. CSV file has

```
IDENTIFIER|AUDIT_ACTION|EMPLID|NAME|EFFDT|LAST_NAME|FIRST_NAME
PERSON_STG|A|731757|Abhijit |01-Oct-2010|SS|Abhijit
PERSON_STG|A|743910|Singh|02-May-2011|S|Arshita
.......................
```

DB has table which has coloumn for each value in CSV file (for example `Emplid`, `Firstname`, `lastname`)

I need to verify that each value in csv seperated with delimiter saved in DB.

I have tried

1. Placing csv file in SFTP and is processed
2. JDBC config and JDBC request to get the values from DB

Can you help on how to compare CSV file JDBC response

Comment: What is the problem, specifically?

Comment: not clear how this even related to JMeter? Can you post the actual script fragment you are trying to work on?

Comment: I need to validate the values in csv is stored successfully in DB. I have writted JDBC output values to CSV file- DB.csv. I have tried Response assertion-${__FileToString(PathtoOriginalCSVfile,,empid)} Apply to Jmeter variable-empid and Patterns to test- ${__FileToString(DB.csv.,,)}. Assertion is failing as JDBC output values has more records.

Answer (score 1):

1. Given you have data in the database which looks like:

   ```
   mysql> select * from cvdata;
   +------------+--------------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------+
   | IDENTIFIER | AUDIT_ACTION | EMPLID | NAME    | EFFDT       | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME |
   +------------+--------------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------+
   | PERSON_STG | A            | 731757 | Abhijit | 01-Oct-2010 | SS        | Abhijit    |
   | PERSON_STG | A            | 743910 | Singh   | 02-May-2011 | S         | Arshita    |
   +------------+--------------+--------+---------+-------------+-----------+------------+
   2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
   ```
2. If you issue a [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) statement in the [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler configured like:

   [image: JMeter JDBC Select Statement]
3. You will get the following [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) (can be visualized using Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination)

   [image: JMeter Variables from CSV]

   See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn more about working with JDBC Requests results in JMeter
4. Add a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to your Test Plan and configure it to iterate `Forever`
5. Add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) as a child of the Loop Controller and configure it like:

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

   The above configuration assumes that your CSV file looks like:

   ```
   IDENTIFIER|AUDIT_ACTION|EMPLID|NAME|EFFDT|LAST_NAME|FIRST_NAME
   PERSON_STG|A|731757|Abhijit |01-Oct-2010|SS|Abhijit
   PERSON_STG|A|743910|Singh|02-May-2011|S|Arshita
   ```

   if it is different - you will need to amend your CSV Data Set Configuration.

   **Note that I intentionally left a white space after `Abhijit` to trigger a test failure for demo purposes**, remove it if you want to check the "happy path"
6. That's almost it, all you need to do now is to compare if

   - `IDENTIFIER` variable is equal to `IDENTIFIER_1` variable on 1st iteration
   - `IDENTIFIER` variable is equal to `IDENTIFIER_2` on 2nd iteration
   - `AUDIT_ACTION` variable is equal to `AUDIT_ACTION_1` on first iteration
   - `AUDIT_ACTION` variable is equal to `AUDIT_ACTION_2` on 2nd iteration
   - etc...

   In order to check these you can add a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the Loop Controller and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   int loop = (vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int) + 1
   if (!vars.get('IDENTIFIER_' + loop).equals(vars.get('IDENTIFIER'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('IDENTIFIER mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('AUDIT_ACTION_' + loop).equals(vars.get('AUDIT_ACTION'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('AUDIT_ACTION mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('EMPLID_' + loop).equals(vars.get('EMPLID'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('EMPLID mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('NAME_' + loop).equals(vars.get('NAME'))) {   
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('NAME mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('EFFDT_' + loop).equals(vars.get('EFFDT'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('EFFDT mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('LAST_NAME_' + loop).equals(vars.get('LAST_NAME'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('LAST_NAME mismatch')
   }
   if (!vars.get('FIRST_NAME_' + loop).equals(vars.get('FIRST_NAME'))) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage('FIRST_NAME mismatch')
   }
   ```

In case of any mismatch it will fail:

[image: JMeter JSR223 Sampler Failure]

Answer (score 0):

Records in CSV is not in same order in DB. DB has more records. So there is mismatch for all the records. How to loop for each coloumn in CSV for example EMPLID value '731757' have to be searched for all the EMPID values in DB, if found, then assertion should pass.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Dxw.png)